# UILabel in UITableView sometimes not showing

Tags: uitableview, ios8

I set in the `.m` file

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    documentCustomCell *cell = (documentCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[documentCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
 cell.titleText.text = cellFileName;
 [cell.titleText setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Please need help 
Doing PDF app

Comment: Please add more information. What is `cellFileName` here? Are you sure it holds a valid value and not `nil`/`Nil`/`NULL`? Have you reloaded the table after the `dataSource` has completed fetching relevant data?

Comment: label have alswayz size and origin it showing warning 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174095900 UITableViewCellContentView:0x174185fe0.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x100b65020.bottom + 72>
what does this mean?

Comment: remove the constraints and check if you are able to see the label as you wish!!!